# pandas series dataindex last get error data

Tags: python, pandas

my data

```
a=  [{"content": 1, "time": 1577870427}, {"content": 4, "time": 1577870427},
     {"content": 6, "time": 1583054427}, {"content": 7, "time": 1583140827},
     {"content": 2, "time": 1577956827},{"content": 5, "time": 1580635227},
     {"content": 3, "time": 1580548827},
     ]
```

my code

```
index = pd.to_datetime([i['time'] for i in a], unit='s')
df = pd.Series(a,index)
print(sort.last('1D'))
```

get error data

```
2020-03-01 09:20:27    {'content': 6, 'time': 1583054427}
2020-03-02 09:20:27    {'content': 7, 'time': 1583140827}
2020-01-02 09:20:27    {'content': 2, 'time': 1577956827}
2020-02-02 09:20:27    {'content': 5, 'time': 1580635227}
2020-02-01 09:20:27    {'content': 3, 'time': 1580548827}
```

why my get error data, is use error,The correct way is？
must use series, thank you

my hope data,i need recent 1 day data

```
res=[{'content': 7, 'time': 1583140827}]
```

Comment: Can you provide us the dataframe. what is sort? What's your expected output?

Comment: @Pygirl  i edit question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method [`Series.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last.html) working correctly with sorted `DatetimeIndex`:

```
print(sort.sort_index())
2020-01-01 09:20:27    {'content': 1, 'time': 1577870427}
2020-01-01 09:20:27    {'content': 4, 'time': 1577870427}
2020-01-02 09:20:27    {'content': 2, 'time': 1577956827}
2020-02-01 09:20:27    {'content': 3, 'time': 1580548827}
2020-02-02 09:20:27    {'content': 5, 'time': 1580635227}
2020-03-01 09:20:27    {'content': 6, 'time': 1583054427}
2020-03-02 09:20:27    {'content': 7, 'time': 1583140827}
dtype: object

print(sort.sort_index().last('1D'))
2020-03-02 09:20:27    {'content': 7, 'time': 1583140827}
dtype: object
```

Comment: if use sort.sort_index().last('1W') 
only one data,actual is two data

Comment: @xin.chen - It return all data by last day only, so possible multiple rows. If want only one, last row, use `sort.sort_index().last('1D').iloc[-1]`